# TypeScript error [TS2741] with mapKeys(camelcase) from lodash

Tags: typescript, lodash

I am trying to type my object but typescript seems unhappy about this:

```
import { camelCase, mapKeys } from 'lodash/fp';

interface QueryResponse {
  accept_card_payments: boolean;
}

interface FinalResponse {
  acceptCardPayments: boolean;
}

const getResponse = () => {
  const toCamelCase = mapKeys(camelCase);
  const queryResponse: QueryResponse = { accept_card_payments: false };
  const response: FinalResponse = toCamelCase(queryResponse); // error TS2741

  return response;

};
```

I got an error in `const response` saying:

```
Property 'acceptCardPayments' is missing in type '
Dictionary<boolean>' but required in type 'FinalResponse'.
```

How can let TypeScript now that my type matches the return value of `mapKeys(camelCase);`?

I made a reproducible example here: https://repl.it/repls/MediumblueRudeBinarysearchtree

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fp types are not perfect and also TS does not support string pattern types so as far as the transform is concerned you are transforming an object into a dictionary and thats it.

**Method 1**

Quick and dirty way would be to acknowledge that using `unknown`:

```
function getFinalResponse(query: QueryResponse): FinalResponse {
  return <FinalResponse>(<unknown>mapKeys(camelCase)(query));
}

const getResponse = (): FinalResponse => {
  return getFinalResponse({ accept_card_payments: false });
};
```

**Method 2**

The fancier way would be to implement a Type Guard function asserting that a type is `FinalResponse` but doing that will lead you through repeating some of the transform again to check if the kebab case function going to give you the key of `QueryResponse`.

```
function assertFinalResponse(
  obj: any,
  query: QueryResponse
): asserts obj is FinalResponse {
  const finalResponseKey = Object.keys(obj)[0];
  if (!Reflect.has(query, kebabCase(finalResponseKey))) {
    throw new Error("Not the right object!");
  }
}

const getResponse2 = (): FinalResponse => {
  const query = { accept_card_payments: false };
  const potentiallyFinal = mapKeys(camelCase)(query);
  assertFinalResponse(potentiallyFinal, query);
  return potentiallyFinal;
};
```